# How to get a value from the buildTextField(a Extracted Widget) of TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter

I had Extracted a Widget And use it multiple times in code
I got Stuck While getting a value from each of the text field

My custom function code is this:

```
  Widget buildTextField(
      IconData icon, String hintText, bool isEmail, dynamic _valueoffield) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: hintText == "Password" ? _isHidden : false,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
        onSubmitted: (_valueoffield) {},
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              icon,
              color: Palette.iconColor,
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Palette.textColor1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Palette.textColor1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Palette.textColor1),
            suffixIcon: hintText == 'Password'
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: _toggleVisibility,
                    icon: _isHidden
                        ? Icon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined)
                        : Icon(Icons.visibility_outlined))
                : null),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to use controllers for TextFields, so instead of `_valueoffield` pass a TextEditingController like this:

```
  TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  ...
  buildTextField(
    ....
    usernameController,
  )
  buildTextField(
    ....
    passwordController,
  )
```

And get values like this

```
String username;
...
username = usernameController.text;
```

So the function will be

```
  Widget buildTextField(
      IconData icon, String hintText, bool isEmail, TextEditingController controller) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: hintText == "Password" ? _isHidden : false,
        keyboardType: isEmail ? TextInputType.emailAddress : TextInputType.text,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              icon,
              color: Palette.iconColor,
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Palette.textColor1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Palette.textColor1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            hintText: hintText,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Palette.textColor1),
            suffixIcon: hintText == 'Password'
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: _toggleVisibility,
                    icon: _isHidden
                        ? Icon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined)
                        : Icon(Icons.visibility_outlined))
                : null),
      ),
    );
  }
```

- I strongly recommend to use `Form` and `TextFormField` for the input fields